# how to manipulate apk variant versioncode

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build-type

The versionCode for the android apk gets set in defaultConfig.  I would like to change for each of my build types but it seems like this can only be done by flavours?  Is there another way to override the versionCode, maybe similar to the way the outputFileName is updated?

Comment: so for example you need to have version codes for debug different from that in release?

Comment: We have staging and release and debug.  Don't care too much about debug but would like staging and release to have different version codes as they point to different services (set through environment variables).
We use the number of commits as our current version code.  But Play won't let us have two different versions with same versionCode.  We would like to change to versionCode * 2 for prod and versionCode * 2 - 1 for staging.

Comment: I think your case fit perfectly with product flavors.. You set a flavor for **prod** and a flavor for **stage**.
In both set version code as your expression (e.g. 300 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode for prod, and 200 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode for release)
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

Then, when you want to run or deploy a version you choose between the 4 combinations in Build Variants that will be: prodRelease, prodDebug, stageRelease and stageDebug

Comment: Except thats more variants than I need, but it looks like the way to go

Comment: But I've now sorted that with the assembleFlavourVariant to pick which one I want

Comment: @LucaCorradi if you put answer in I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your case fit perfectly with product flavors.

You set a flavor for prod and a flavor for stage. In both set version code as your expression (e.g. 300 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode for prod, and 200 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode for release)

> See the doc for detailed examples:
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

Then, when you want to run or deploy a version you choose between the 4 combinations in Build Variants that will be: *prodRelease*, *prodDebug*, *stageRelease* and *stageDebug*

Answer (score 0):

You can create different AndroidManifest.xml for each buildType you have, and then set the versionCode in the manifest, but in my personal opinion you should use flavors.

Answer (score 0):

In your project root build.gradle you could define version code and version Name some thing like this

```
  def code = project.hasProperty('versionCode') ? versionCode.toInteger() : 
        (System.getenv("VERSION_CODE") as Integer ?: <default-version-code>)

  def name = project.hasProperty('versionName') ? versionName.toString() : 
  (System.getenv("VERSION_NAME") as String ?: "<default-version-name>")
```

You could provide version code and name runtime in the build command something like this 
 -P = value

```
 allprojects {
    ext.baseVersionCode = code
    ext.baseVersionName = name    
}
```

These version code your could access in you all modules.In the app build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    versionCode baseVersionCode
    versionName baseVersionName
    archivesBaseName = "customzied_apk_name"
}
```